# How to make sure to have always enough disc space by deleting files from directories that are the oldest

Tags: windows, logrotate

I want to make sure that the server we use for logging certain things never runs out of disc space because of too many logs. The oldest logs shall be deleted when disc space is running low. Are there tools for this? In Linux there is rotate when I remember correctly. But in Windows? It is not about one log file but several log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [scheduled task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Schedule-a-task) that executes [a batch file which deletes files older than x days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days). The task can then be scheduled to be run daily, monthly, whatever.